# Can I use Caliper to measure private ethereum chain whose nodes are ubuntu docker nodes?

Tags: go-ethereum

I use 3 docker containers as ubuntu nodes, and on each ubuntu I use geth to make it a ethereum node. And I connected these 3 nodes as a private chain.(geth v1.11) I wonder if I can deploy contract on it and measure the latency and throughput by using Hyper Caliper? I remember when configure the network it uses http. Does it matter?